# Can I apply CSS styles to part of document

Tags: html, css, backend

For example, I have a frontend and backend sites that uses different templates and styles. There is a workflow - the manager edits page text with the WYSIWYG editor and saves it and he wants to see the result.

It would be very user friendly when he will stay in backend and will be able to see just edited text inline on page, in backend content div, but with frontend styles.

Let's assume, that we need to see only text formatting styles, and we have separate css file with this styles.

My solutions:

1)Create page with custom layout (only content div) and show in backend as iframe.

2) Process css file and prepend backend div class name selector to every rule in this css. Then print style tag with processed css.

Is there more elegant solution for this issue? Some @begin_style @end_style?

Thanks!

Comment: It's too bad [`<style scoped>`](http://davidwalsh.name/scoped-css) isn't fully supported yet.

Comment: Interesting, scoped is that I am looking for.